# Возобновление работы потока при уменьшении элементов в коллекции

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, когда я использую `BlockingCollection<>` по назначению, она реализует потокобезопасное добавление и изъятие элементов из коллекции, при этом поток "просыпается" только когда надо добавить новый элемент или выдать по запросу.
Хочу использовать эту коллекцию из-за её потокобезопасности, немного иначе:
1. Чтобы коллекция всегда содержала в себе n-количество элементов(например 10).
2. В любой момент получать готовый элемент.
3. При изъятии одного элемента, поток в фоне должен добавлять новые элементы согласно максимальному количеству.

Вот код

```
static class Class1
    {
        //максимальное количество элементов в коллекции
        static int MaxElementInCollection = 10;
        //рабочий поток
        static Thread Thread;
        //коллекция с элементами
        static BlockingCollection<ObjectToReturn> collection = new BlockingCollection<ObjectToReturn>();

        //функция которая запускает поток
        static void LaunchThread()
        {
            Thread = new Thread(ThreadWork);
            Thread.Start();
        }

        //метод который возвращает готовый объект, по запросу
        static ObjectToReturn ReturnObject()
        {
            ObjectToReturn ObjectToReturn;
            collection.TryTake(out ObjectToReturn);
            return ObjectToReturn;
        }

        //метод который добавляет элементы в коллекцию при их уменьшении
        static void ThreadWork()
        {
            while(collection.Count < MaxElementInCollection)            
                collection.Add(new ObjectToReturn(5));                        
        }
    }

    class ObjectToReturn
    {
        int a;
        public ObjectToReturn(int a)
        {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }
```

Но после того как функция `ThreadWork()` выполняется один раз, поток "умирает". 

Как заставить его "спать" до того момента пока количество элементов не уменьшится? Не создавать же его заново, и бесконечный цикл не подходит, потому что загружает процессор.
Или использовать `ThreadPool` после каждого вызова `ReturnObject()`, что тоже не подходит, потому что при частом вызове несколько потоков будут соревноваться за то чтобы добавить новый элемент в коллекцию, т.е делать это должен один поток.
Буду благодарен за ссылки по теме и советы!

Comment: Может быть имеет смысл совсем пересмотреть алгоритм работы: отказаться от `Thread`, а для получения следующего элемента использовать `yield return`, а с помощью события пополнять коллекцию элементов?

Comment: @Bulson, события предполагают выполнения всего кода, т.е. вызвав например событие `onEvent()` управление не вернется пока не будет выполнен весь код подписанных на это событие методов. Например если после того как забирать один элемент из коллекции, вызывать событие - это не приемлемо. Ну и если по вызову события `onEvent()` запускать Thread, затраты на создание нового потока окажутся слишком большими, как я понимаю

Comment: `async/await` использовать для методов извлечения и пополнения коллекции? Вполне годный вариант, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @Bulson, спасибо, до этого не пользовался `async/await` почитаю подробнее!

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую!

Создавать новый поток нет необходимости, Вы можете усыплять ваш существующий поток на незначительное время, после этого проверять состояние вашей коллекции, при необходимости добавлять в нее элемент, все это дело в управляемом бесконечном цикле с флагом. При закрытии приложения просто отсылайте `stopFlag=true`

```
while (!stopFlag)
        {
            CheckCollection();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Comment: Вы невнимательно прочитали автора вопроса: "... и бесконечный цикл не подходит, потому что загружает процессор."

Comment: @Bulson нагрузка на процессор минимальна, т.к. новые потоки не плодятся, к тому же, нагрузку можно регулировать временем сна. Чем больше спим - тем меньше работы нашему CPU. Автор пусть сам решает, с какой частотой ему надо чекать коллекцию.

Comment: @Exodium, спасибо, за ответ, от такой конструкции отказался почти сразу, из-за того, что возможна ситуация когда коллекция с элементами окажется пуста(все забрали) и нужно будет получить элемент, а поток который их добавляет спит, в этом случае можно написать логику создания нового объекта в обход коллекции, но это крайний способ которым хочу воспользоваться. Т.к есть цель разобраться с работой потоков лучше и все-таки реализовать более "умный" алгоритм.

Comment: @K.Oleg мне просто интересно, Вы хотите отказаться от событий но при этом иметь возможность всегда получать элемент из коллекции. Мне кажется такой подход не реализуем без событийной модели, то есть если элементы будут добавляться по таймеру а не по изъятию, то ситуация отсутствия элементов не исключена.

Comment: @Exodium, отказываться ни от чего не хочу, если после вызова события будет выполняться одна строчка кода которая будет будить поток(не создавать новый), и сразу возвращать управление, это будет самым наилучшим решением, вот и мой вопрос заключается в том, как реализовать механизм "пробуждения" Thread, с помощью событий или без.

Comment: @K.Oleg ну могу сказать что async/await не панацея, т.к. все равно для выполнения вашей Task<T> будет создан дополнительный фоновый поток, хоть и код после await будет выполнен в основном потоке, запустившем Task.

Comment: @K.Oleg но т.к. вы используете коллекцию с поддержкой Concurrency, то несколько фоновых потоков, порожденных для выполнения  Task<T>, в полной мере смогут работать с ней.

Comment: @Bulson, а как по вашему мнению в этом случае исключить такую последовательность: большое количество запросов нового объекта и большое количество созданных фоновых потоков, которые будут соревноваться за блокировку коллекции, для добавления в нее "свежих" элементов?

Comment: В этом случае вам поможет ConcurrentQueue и ее методы TryEnqueue и TryDequeue